# Increase/decrease/reset font size not working

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set up a increase/decrease/reset font size option on my web server but it doesn't seem to be working. I want all elements to resize (i.e. headers, buttons, modal windows and so on)

This is my code so far, I've included a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/R3NGU/3/

```
 var originalFontSize = $('.page').css('font-size');

 // reset font size

 $(".resetFont").click(function () {
     $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
 });

 // increase font Size

 $(".increaseFont").click(function () {
     var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
     var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
     var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 1.2;
     $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
     return false;
 });

 // decrease font size

 $(".decreaseFont").click(function () {
     var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
     var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
     var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 0.8;
     $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: That's because you have hardcoded font sizes for other elements in your stylesheet.

Comment: If you're changing the html font size, all the elements inside your page must use any measurement unit apart from pixels or points. EM, REM and % are the ones to go on your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
```

use the [wildcard all selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/):

```
$('*').css('font-size', newFontSize);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/R3NGU/4/)**

Comment: This would mess the whole site up if you define the font size on the html and use rem as measurement units for the rest of your site.

Answer (score 0):

i use this to decrease all font size for each element

```
jQuery('body').each(function(index) {
    jQuery(this).find('*').each(function() {

    var cur_size =  jQuery(this).css('font-size');
   //alert(cur_size);
    cur_size = cur_size.replace("px",""); 
   jQuery(this).css('font-size', (cur_size - 2));
    });
});
```